# How do I keep my Christmas tree from falling over?

Tags: safety, interior

It never fails: I bring home a 9-foot pine, cut the trunk flat, remove the lower branches, and place our Christmas tree in the stand only to have it fall over a little later in the evening.

How can I prevent this "Christmas tradition" from ever happening again?

Comment: I cleaned up some of the side conversation because it bordered on a rant and wasn't constructive (per the [faq]).

Comment: You let your tree thaw out before  attempting to get it balanced and tightened in place, right? They spread out as theuy warm, and the balance does change.

Comment: @WayfaringStranger I live in Southern California, so I don't usually worry about frozen trees. In any case we let the branches settle for a few hours at least.

Comment: The place I got my tree from, cut about 1 1/2 inch from the trunk, and my son was gonna use it as a car refreshener, but after reading all your suggestions, I gave it a try and my tree stopped falling or tilting, thank you so much, and Merry Christmas to all.

Comment: Wire it to the ceiling.

Answer (score 17):

### Get a heavy stand

Growing up, my dad had a traditional stand that looks something like this:

[image: Traditional flimsy tree stand]

That works for smaller trees as long as you can be sure that nobody (such as a child or pet) will disturb it.  That's not at all a given.  Remember that trees have [extensive root systems](http://www.auburn.edu/academic/forestry_wildlife/longleafalliance/ecosystem/longleaftree/longleaftree3.htm) that keep them grounded during windy periods and so it's important to get a stand that can simulate the parts of the tree that have been cut off.  For that reason, I'm a proponent of a heavier stand such as this one made of cast iron:

[image: Cast iron tree stand]

There's something to be said for the simplicity of a really heavy, wide stand that will hold your tree firmly in place.  I've been told plastic stands are sturdier than they look when they are weighted with water.  They have the additional advantage of holding a gallon of water or more, which means you won't risk a dried out tree.  In some ways it doesn't matter what the stand *looks like* since you can always cover it with a tree skirt.  (And my wife insists on it even though I like the way our stand looks.)

### Placing the tree in the stand

One thing I've tried is to set the tree up before removing the twine that holds the branches in place.  This is a mistake for two reasons:

1. The balance of the tree changes when the branches are fully deployed.  A tree that stands straight when wrapped can sometimes end up leaning when unwrapped.
2. My wife always wants me to rotate the tree so that the best side is facing into the room.  Once the tree is secure, you don't want to mess with the balance by trying to move or rotate it.

For the sake of getting a good balance, I also think it's a mistake to attach the stand before putting the tree upright.  Or rather, you're going to need to readjust it anyway and it probably won't buy you anything—especially if you have a heavy stand.

### Attaching the tree to the stand

Here's where my stand fails me.  It attaches to the tree with three screws.  Three is the absolute minimum number of points need to hold a trunk in place and it doesn't seem to be enough.  If I try to adjust one side, the tree starts falling over and I need help holding it up.  (My father's stand had the same problem, but image searches show most of the traditional design have 4 screws plus a ring to hold the truck more securely.)

This year I hit on a solution that's so simple I can't figure out how it didn't occur to me before: I put 2x4 scraps between the screws and the trunk.  This has the advantage of spreading the side pressure to a larger area and also makes adjustments easier since the bolts don't screw into the trunk itself.  For added security, I packing in extra scraps of wood to brace the tree now that I have it secured to the stand.

Looking around, I see that newer designs use two levels of screws or even "hug" the trunk with a pedal operated cable.  I don't have any experience with these designs, but if the stand is heavy enough (see above) they are probably improvements over the three-screw stand that I'm using.

### Consider a guyline

Here in California, we are encouraged to secure everything in case of earthquake.  Given the excitement of the season, I like to secure our tree in case of childquake.  It's a bit of a hassle, but in years past, I've been glad to have a bit of safety from tree fall when its balance shifted due to watering and decorations.  It need not be an eyesore either—the line might be secured to a hook in the wall behind the tree.

I've used monofilament fishing line to attach our tree to a hook in the ceiling.  Since the fishing line is designed to be invisible (or close to it) in water, most people won't see it.  A bonus advantage is that you know what your line is rated and can estimate how many strands will suffice.  If you *do* fish in the summer, its a good idea to replace your line between fishing seasons to avoid tangles, so this is a perfect opportunity.

Comment: +1 for the guyline, used them every year in Maine. Cats man, cats and Christmas trees.

Comment: +1 for packing wedges. We have a plastic, water filled stand, and the 3 screws weren't enough. With wedges it works perfectly.

Comment: Must be a Maine thing because our cat loved to try to pull over the tree. She is 16 now and much better behaved. Happy to lay under the tree and not play with all the ornaments  lol  I used mono fishing line to secure it to the back wall and ceiling.

Comment: My mother loads her Christmas tree down with so many ornaments that until we started using a guyline, it fell at least twice a season. We use clear fishing line as the guyline, it's invisible unless you know it's there.

Comment: @Malfist et al.: I added the suggestion to use fishing line.  I don't have much luck with it myself, however, since I usually go to small streams and tiny lakes so my line is rated for far less than is needed to keep a tree from tipping over without a lot of strands.  This year I used some twine anchored on the backside of the tree, which is nearly as unobtrusive.  Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: If you can't get a heavy tree stand, take one of the lighter ones, and screw it to a short but wide box (2 footx2 foot or larger) made of plywood and 2x4's (screw the plywood down to the 2x4s so you get a short space under the box). If you get the stand attached well, you'll have a MUCH more tip resistant stand. You still have to get the tree in correctly, but at least you'll have a fighting chance.

Comment: @shirlockhomes Huh, definitely didn't have you pegged as a cat person.

Comment: I have always had cats and dogs. My wife won't let me have a dog anymore.

Comment: So now I just got my killer 24 pound cat, Rosie, she loves me but is mean as hell.  lol. She thinks she is a guard dog.   LOL

Comment: We have a carpeted floor -- I use a piece of 1/4" plywood under the stand to make it easier to adjust the position of the tree.   We usually get a 9-10' tree, and I can drag it by pulling on a corner of the plywood while we're finding the best side, and to fine-tune the location before trimming it.

Comment: Thanks for the fishing line idea, would never have occurred to me.

Comment: Fishing line has always worked well on my tree of heavy ornaments and curious pooch.

Comment: Although I agree and will up vote this answer, I used to have a home with 18' vaulted ceilings that we put 16 foot trees in. The hardest part was getting it through the double doors. Our stand was a simple steel plate that a 4" pipe had been welded , 3 double sets of screws adjusted the tree, although we did have a huge cat that climbed several of the trees they never toppled With several trunks of decorations and lights if the tree was true or upright with no lean we did not have a problem. The base was 3- maybe 3-1/2 feet wide compared to the little stand we use today with only 9' ceilings.

Answer (score 6):

I'm going to presume you have a fairly standard type of christmas tree stand, like this one, however much of what I am saying applies to other sorts of standsthat rely on similar mechanics.
[image: standard christmas tree stand]

Notice, at the bottom of the stand the little red trianglar tabs that stick up vertically? They are important in preventing your tree from tipping. Before tightening the bolts, you should place the tree trunk in the center of the stand, vertical, and hold on firmly to the trunk of the tree and push downward to **insert the red tabs into the base of the tree**. You may want to get an assistant to help you push the tree downward if you can't get enough downward pressure by yourself. And if you still can't get enough impact, lay the tree on it's side and use a hammer on the bottom side of the stand to attach the tabs. If you don't push the tree into the tabs, uneven weight of branches or ornaments could lead to excess force on one of the bolts, causing it to gouge out a portion of the tree and cause unplanned tipping.

Then you should double check the tree is perfectly vertical, and **tighten the bolts**. The bolts should reach into the tree about an inch to be secure, or use an attachment style such as pads or blocks with large flat surfaces that hold the tree like a clamp. Depending on the size of your stand and the diameter of your tree's trunk, you may need to **replace the bolts with slightly longer ones** to get a tight enough secure fit. We've had to do that before, and it helps a lot if the diameter of the trunk is not *quite* what you need for the stand, but using a smaller stand would be insufficiently sized. And make sure the tree is perfectly straight before tightening the bolts. Have an assistant hold it straight while you tighten. You don't want to start over on tightening the bolts as it will decrease the snugness of your bolts.

Also make sure the **stand you have is an adequate size** for the tree you have selected. The **base should be broad**/wide and a large bowl for water, and (including the water) significantly **heavy enough** to prevent easy tipping/knocking over. The bigger the tree you have, the more substantial of a stand you will need. The stand I have pictured is rated for trees up to 8' tall, so it may not be adequately sized, weighted, and broad based enough for a 9' tree, even if the tree trunk fits in the stand. One rule of thumb is the width of the stand should be at least 1/3 the width of the tree branches on the bottom level, if not larger.

Answer (score 5):

I dunno, but if you can't rotate the tree once it's in the stand without fear of it toppling, you're doing something wrong.

1. Make sure the stand is appropriately sized for the tree. A 9-foot tree is quite big, and will need an extra-large stand of some sort. Don't think you can get by with your dad's old red-and-green stand just because he successfully used it for 30 years (unless of course your dad always got 10-foot trees, too).
2. *Make sure the trunk **hits the bottom of the stand***. If there's any gap, it's just not gonna work. (To see why, try holding a heavy frying pan vertically, with the pan part up, just by pinching the handle between your thumb and forefinger.)
   [image: Diagram of tree in stand] This is probably the most common problem encountered with the usual types of tree stands, because most trees just don't have very long trunks below the lowest level of branches. If you can't lop off a layer of branches for fear of ruining the look of the tree, put a scrap piece of wood or two in the bottom of the stand, to fill the gap.
3. You really shouldn't need guylines unless you have a particularly excitable Irish Wolfhound or two-year-old in the house. If you do have such critters, consider getting a smaller tree and putting it on a table, at least until the dog (or the child) grows up a bit and is less of a danger.

Comment: Yeah, I've never bothered with the red-and-green stands.  Avoiding the gap is yet another reason to put the tree in the stand vertically rather horizontally.  (I can't say this has ever been an issue.) As for the guyline, I don't think I need it this year, but it is a comfort.

Answer (score 1):

I find that most consumer stands are junk.

My parents have a great-room with 18' ceilings, so they always have a massive tree. The only stand I've ever seen work to stabilize large trees is a metal ring stand like this one:

http://www.alpinefarms.com/wholesale/christmas-tree-stands/#.UMIuQYNlEtU

I see here that they come in various sizes. This ring stand is easily covered by a decorative tree blanket. My father set up boxes covered in craft-paper and did a little christmas town screne thing under it.

You can easily level the tree with wedges under the ring.

Answer (score 1):

We have a hook in the ceiling and tie the top part of the tree to the ceiling hook using a trucker's hitch & dental floss.  The hook is left in place year round and is painted the same color as the ceiling.   No one notices it.

Our house is owned by 3 cats.   We have had no tree mishaps since doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had your dilemma. It wasn't pretty.
My solution was to cut two one inch discs from the
end of the tree trunk. In my case these were discarded in the
garage. I used these discs as shims/wedges between the
screws of the stand. It made the tree more secure and so far
the tree has held firm. By the way I only placed the 
discs/wedges on either side of the tree the way it fell.

Answer (score 0):

I have put up trees to 12 ft, stands can hardly hold a 5 ft. tree. I tie them off to hooks in two walls ; preferable locate the tree in a corner. No one notices white nylon cord , or put tinsel on the cord as part of decorations. As @Dan says , celling works but I think two walls is more stable.